# Specifying Python code to be used on user form for QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

Previously, on QGIS 2.18, I followed this well known tutorial to create a user form with some basic Python driven buttons.
https://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/

The QGIS 3 layer properties interface no longer has the setting (at least not in the same place, so I can't find it) which tells QGIS to run a Python script on opening the form. This is discussed in the tutorial in the section headed "almost done".

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question (I'm sure other people will struggle with this).
The interface DOES have the same setting in the same place - but whereas on QGIS 2.18 there is an obvious box into which the details of the script are written (as in the tutorial) on QGIS 3 is a small button with a python icon on it. Once you've noticed it it's obvious.